# Python Multiprocessing how to set to not wait for other works to finish

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pool

I have a multiprocessing call as below. In the current iteration, NCPUS_FOLDER is set to 4. I noticed that when 2 of the jobs are done, the worker does not immediately proceed to the next 2 tasks in RUN_DIRS. I assume they are waiting for the other 2 workers to finish. When I looked up this issue, all I can find are people asking how to make the workers wait and solutions include using the async versions, while it seems my default is that they are waiting when I want to make them not wait. Is it because of how I am using the pool feature? How do I tell the workers that completed the job to continue?

```
from multiprocess import Pool
if __name__ == '__main__':
  t0 = time.time()
  with Pool(NCPUS_FOLDER) as pool:
    # Assign folders
    pool.map(main,RUN_DIRS)
  print(f"Ending total run in {time.time()-t0:.1f} seconds")
```

The main code. Each parallel worker calls an optimization solver and completes when the print statement is printed. In my case, 2 of the 4 parallel jobs printed the run complete statement, but doesn't begin 2 new jobs. During the constraint and cost function evaluations, it will create folders, write files, etc.

```
def main(run_dir):
  os.chdir(run_dir)
  
  # create a nested solver
  solver = BuckshotSolver(dim=len(TARGET), npts=4)
  # since we have an search solver
  # we specify what optimization algorithm to use within the search
  solver.SetNestedSolver(PowellDirectionalSolver)

  # set the constraint
  solver.SetConstraints(constraint_func)

  # find the minimum
  # pass the termination condition
  solver.Solve(cost_func, termination=VTR(tolerance=TOLERANCE),disp=True)

  print(f"The best solution in {run_dir} is {solver.bestSolution}")
```

Comment: How do you know that the worker doesn't proceed immediately?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Because when the worker proceeds, it will create folders, call jobs, call external applications, print progress messages, etc. None of this happens.

Comment: it is not waiting for other jobs here.

Comment: Please add the simplest `main()` that causes the problem.

Comment: What is the value of NCPUS_FOLDER? And `len(RUN_DIRS)`? And what operating system are you using? And have you tried setting NCPUS_FOLDER=1? And have you run the solver sequentially in each directory?